# Android Sliding Tabs - modifying sample project

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to create a sliding tabs app like the one in the screenshot below although due to the lack of samples available, this one is the closest I could find for what I want to achieve.

I would be very grateful if anybody could help me with following:

1. Which Java code needs to be removed in order to safely get rid of the colour picker at the bottom + what codes needs to replace it so that I can use a hex colour of my choice for the Action bar, Indicator colour, Tab titles, Tab backgrounds and Tab separators.
2. Which code (Java and/or XML) needs to change so that I can use XML fragment files of my own rather than these 'cards'.

All help would be very much appreciated as there is literally no sample project out there that does what I want to achieve.

The link to the sample project that I intend to modify is below.

LINK:  [astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip · GitHub](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

[image: Sliding tabs goal]

**Tabs**

[image: tabs]

**slidingTabs & my_tab_text_view**

[image: tabs n text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well for fragments of your own did you have a look at `ViewPager`? http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Also have a look at android sample code: https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html

for controlling the actionBar: have a look at the new ToolBar api
https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

after that if you still have questions you are welcome to ask

```
 slidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
 slidingTabLayout.setDividerColors(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
 slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
```

add this method to SlidingTabLayout

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {



    /**
    * #####################Add THIS METHOD ############
    *
    * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
    * @param textViewId  id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
    */
   public void setCustomTabView (int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
       mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
       mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
   }
...
}
```

from your activity:

```
public void onCreate(){
    slidingTabs.setCustomTabView(0, R.layout.my_tab_text_view)
}
```

where my_tab_text_view is a layout file:

```
<TextView

          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

just make sure that width is 0 and weight is 1

Comment: OK just followed it and it works but how can I get the tabs to fill up the whole width of the available space as at the moment they are squashed together. Check screenshot above titled **Tabs**.

Comment: for that you need a custom TextView with weights for each one on the width. updated my answer in order to help.

Comment: Where did you get `slidingTabs` and `my_tab_text_view` from?

Comment: you need to manualy add this method to the SlidingTabLatyout class...It's not a static method

Comment: OK cool. Only error I'm left with now is `slidingTabs` as is says Cannot resolve symbol `slidingTabs`

Comment: What were you referring to as 'slidingTabs'?

Comment: have a look at android sample code: https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just set the width and weight programmatically? Something like this?: `textView.setWidth(0);` and `textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));`

Comment: Had a look but I can't find that line of code or any other line similar to that one. Also there is no XML file for that text box within the project.